# how do I search my whole php project for extra characters before the opening php tag

Tags: php, eclipse

This question was probably asked before, but I can't find it with my search.

How do I search my whole php project for extra characters or lines before the opening php tag
    <?php which cause headers and ajax problems.

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how to do a search (while it's certainly possible using a smart regex), but if you have problems with the "headers already sent" message, you should get a line number telling you where the first byte of data came from.

Comment: some regex, or "brute force" :D, fire up some programming IDE and search for <? or <?php in the whole project. but i too think that the error should have and error line and file start and trace backwards from there.

Comment: Something like PHP mess dedector or http://cs.sensiolabs.org/ the psr fixer should do the trick.

Comment: [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator `](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) + [`file_get_contents `](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) + [`preg_match`](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) - Alternatively check out [grep beginning of file?](http://superuser.com/questions/119274/grep-beginning-of-file)

Comment: What is the real problem here ? any error log of undesired effect ? @Pekka : that error message is mostly seen when dealing with session data, but it can/will fail silently when designing ajax UX, breaking the layout and leaving you with solutions like **Leigh** gave. As a reminder, **sdfor** should apply the same grep'ing to the script ending. An extra space character at the end can ruin your templates.

Answer (score 1):

Fire up a text editor with a RegEx search capabilities and search for a 
`/.+<\?php/gsm`
Based on a RegEx-search implementation, it may be
`.+<\?php`
with *global*, *dotall* and *multiline* flags enabled.

Note: this regex will match files with more than one opening `<?php` tag. If you have many of that files you need a bit more complex solution.